# The title, link and description don't work

Tags: facebook, caching, hyperlink, share

I've been reading guides and examples for a long time (hours) but I can't manage. I tried to use all html meta tag like title, description, and og:property. Also tried to use the link sharer and also to create a new blank page with just the info I want to share to facebook in order to test. Also I tried to generate an random url in php so to have always a different url variable (the url to share and also the url of the main page containing the script). I also grabbed (url linter) a lot of time the url to clean the cache of facebook. It always give me the title of the site domain as title or the url itself as the shared title and description. I don't know what to do.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't use things like "Urgent" or "Please help" or "ASAP" in your question title. People here help others on a voluntary basis, and while your question may seem very urgent or important to you, others have questions too. If you need help badly enough that you can't wait, you should probably hire someone who can give you their immediate undivided attention. The cries of "urgent" and "ASAP" simply add clutter and noise, and make it harder to dig out the details of your problem. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the title is locked in, meaning that after X number of likes Facebook doesn't allow you to change it anymore.  Can you give us an example URL you're having issues with?

**EDIT**

Ok, now the link you provided shows some very interesting output. http://modernolatina.it/wjs/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=258&autore=6&articolo=6

First, you webserver, instead of sending back a 200 code, is sending back a 500 code.
Secondly the HTML your webserver is sending back has two HTML tags (Do a view source on the content returned)

Fix up those two issues and I think the linter will be happier with your page.

Test your page here:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: An example is [link](http://modernolatina.it/wjs/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&Itemid=258&autore=6&articolo=6)

Answer (score 0):

The main web site is from joomla. In the code of index of joomla I put a php include if the url has the variable "articolo" id. This incuded php page has regulat head body etc. So maybe I facebook check the main meta of joomla first? So now I tried to open a popup with just the page for sharing. Look here: [link](http://www.modernolatina.it/wjs/blog/fb/index.php?articolo=6)

Comment: If you have additional information to include, you should edit your original question, or possibly add a clarifying comment.  Adding additional information in an answer to your own question is not the right way to do it.